# Does anyone manufacture a 10 keyless with "normal" arrow and home/end layout and low, silent keys

Tags: keyboards

For coding and writing text I need a normal keyboard with a "normal" arrow and delete/home/end/page-down/page-up layout but I don't need the numpad at all. Without the numpad I can keep the mouse in a much more ergonomic position.

For a long time I used the Logitech Mediapad but that is discontinued since some years.
[image]

For a couple of years I used the CM Quickfire which has perfect layout but Cherry MX switches are both too high to be ergonomic for me and also to loud for an office landscape.

[image]

Does anyone know of a standard, office-friendly keyboard that comes without a numpad?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The type of keyboard you are looking for is called "Ten Key Less". Or TKL in short.

Sadly, it seems like they rarely come in membrane form. I haven't seen a single one in all of newegg and amazon.

I think your best best is the Logitech G Pro Mechanical Gaming. It has Romer-G switches, which aren't too noisy, and is in the format you want.

[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XMRQ68B)

[image]

If you want a more silent solution and don't mind too much the Cherry MX, there's a Red Silent version now. If you want one that looks fine in an office environment, consider this model:
[Durgod Taurus](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QK16RDQ)
[image]

For a comparison of the level of noise of MX vs RomerG check out this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ys-W0cHUDs

Comment: I kind of understand your pain. I like my lower profiled membrane keyboard compared to the mechanical ones. But it seems like no one wants to make a low-profiled 87key/TKL keyboard. Just checked through hundreds of different keyboards with that layout: all mechanical. Even the chinese ones.

Comment: Keep in mind that all Cherry MX switches, and most other mechanical switches, have removable keycaps with a standard peg/socket. You could search for a low profile keycap set and replace the keys on almost any TKL board.